# Status of oracle job is DONE (ERROR), but job is never finished

Tags: oracle

V$SQL_MONITOR displays status of my job as DONE (ERROR) - Execution terminated with an error. But job is never finished. It happens time to time, not always. Any hint will be appreciated

UPDATE:
I run jobs with PL/SQL command

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB ( job_name=> cName,use_current_session => FALSE)
```

Usually it is PL/SQL scripts.
To check is it still running I run

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.STOP_JOB (job_name  => cName,force     => FALSE);
```

If I don't get ORA-27366 (An attempt was made to stop a job that was not running) it means IMO that it is still running. So I set force=>TRUE and it have stopped

Comment: Can you add more context? What job? How did you schedule it? How do you know the job never finished? Maybe the database did a rollback (because error) and it just looks like it never finished?

Comment: Many thanks for reasonable remark, updated post

Comment: Maybe you can take a look in the system view `all_scheduler_job_run_details` to see which errors are logged.

Comment: Thank you, but there is only REASON="Stop job with force called by user. " for this job. It is true...

Comment: Then maybe your job was still running even though there was a SQL statement with an error in `v$sql_monitor` (that view monitors queries not jobs).

Comment: Thanks, no, it is not, there are already nothing to do in job. Usually it happens with last commit. And there is not a lot of data in this commit, some records